# Cannot send a DEBUG request to IIS Express ("404 Not Found")

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api, jetbrains, rider

Использую Rider + IIS Express (10.0). При запуске ASP .NEt Core 3.1.406 API приложение отрабатывает, но при запуске в дебаге вылетает ошибка Cannot send a DEBUG request to IIS Express ("404 Not Found"). It may indicate an invalid "applicationUrl" parameter in your launchSettings.json. Please check your settings.